# Procmail recipe that will execute a script without affecting delivery?

Tags: linux, procmail

How do I write a procmail recipe that executes a shell script without affecting delivery?(in this case, something that sends me a DM via Twitter)

I don't want to affect further processing of the message - it should continue on its way and the output of the script should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `c` flag.